# Which reindex option do I use to reindex an index in order to upgrade open search?

Tags: amazon-opensearch

I need to update an Amazon open search cluster to a new version. In order to do this, I need to [reindex the incompatible indexes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/version-migration.html)

However, there is no information provided in this guide on how to do this.

According to the [reindex docs](https://opensearch.org/docs/1.0/opensearch/reindex-data/), I can reindex all indexes with some provided settings. However, I am not sure which settings to provide. If I provide the same settings as the existing index, nothing will have been accomplished. It will be a copy of the same data in the same format.